# Can't get Wikipedia summary API redirects working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, wikipedia-api

I'm using PHP cURL and jQuery to make an ajax call to this api by adding the country name to the end of the url: https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/

The country name is saved in a variable by looping through the restcountries.eu API and getting the country 'name'. Everything works fine except for countries whose names don't exactly match, eg: Bahamas vs The Bahamas, United Kingdom vs United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland. If I type these in manually wikipeadia automatically redirects correctly.

I've tried adding '&redirects' to the end of the url (in PHP) but that doesn't work, the detail key has a value of "Page or revision not found." If I just pass the saved variable "Bahamas" without '&redirect'  the wikipedia api returned data object is 'null'.

Btw my 'countryName' variable used .replace(/\s+/g, '_') and I have no problems with standard names like Trinidad and Tobago or Papua New Guinea.

Another example, if in the php I hard code $url='https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Northern_Ireland';
the data object I get is 'null'

but if I just past the same url in a browser it redirects to https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/United_Kingdom automatically.

How can I get the redirects working?

my php code:

```
<?php

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true) / 1000;
    $url='https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/'. $_REQUEST['place'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = "200";
    $output['status']['name'] = "ok";
    $output['status']['description'] = "mission saved";
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = (microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) / 1000 . " ms";
    $output['data'] = $decode;
    
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output); 

?>
```

my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "libs/php/wiki.php",
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        place: countryName 
      }, 
      success: function(result) {                  
         console.log('wiki info', result);      
           if (result.status.name == "ok") {
             $('#txtWikiImg').html('<img src=' + result.data.thumbnail.source +'><br>');
             $('#txtWiki').html('Wikipedia: ' + result.data.extract +'<br>');
           } 
        },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: And why you're using php file instead of get a data from wikipedia directly by using the ajax only by set the value of `url :'wiki_api_url'+countryname`  and you can still add key-values to the returned data

Comment: First, thank you! Your solution works. I've just been using cURL to handle all my api requests. I do have a question about making the ajax call directly. Shouldn't I have some error handling?  The returned object doesn't come with any status code.

Comment: If the url is fine and data returned this means its ok and it will print out in the ajax success callback .. if the url is wrong it will show the error in the ajax error callback .. So you don't need to check for the status

Comment: Ah great. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You're totally welcome :-)

Comment: Just set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true.

Comment: Thank you Tgr! This solved the original problem. Thank you so much for the help.